# Publishing to RabbitMQ silently fails in the parent process after forking a child

Tags: perl, rabbitmq, fork

I'm running into perplexing behavior with Net::AMQP::RabbitMQ and fork().  If I...

1. Establish a connection to RabbitMQ in the parent process
2. Publish a message
3. Fork a child and wait for it to exit (the child sleeps)
4. Publish a message

... the second message is not actually sent to RabbitMQ (and no errors are thrown).  I've done a lot of tests, including checking `$connection->is_connected()` before sending.  A few interesting tidbits from my experimentation:

- If I try to open a new channel before publishing the second message, the `$connection->open_channel( $newChannelId )` call hangs.
- If I allow the child to continue running while the parent publishes the second message (and wait until afterwards to `waitpid`) it's successfully sent.

I'm looking for a way to detect that this connection is no longer valid when a forked child exits, and force a disconnect/reconnect.  I'm caching the connection in a perl module that is used by various other modules in the system and I don't know if/when those other modules `fork()` to do work in parallel.  I can't reliably set a `$SIG{CHLD}` handler and drop the connection when the signal is received because other code might overwrite my handler.  The only bulletproof option I have is to discard the cache and connect for each message, but this slows down publish rates considerably (by a factor of 30ish).

This script demonstrates the issue (publishing to a topic exchange called 'broadcast'):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use Net::AMQP::RabbitMQ;
use JSON -support_by_pp;

my $connection;
my $channelId = 0;

sub sendToRabbit {
  my ($message) = @_;
  print "Sending message $message->{message}\n";
  my $contentType = 'application/json';
  my $payload = encode_json $message;
  $connection->publish($channelId, 'test.route', $payload, { exchange => 'broadcast', force_utf8_in_header_strings => 1 }, { 'content_type' => $contentType });
  print "Sent!\n";
}

sub main {
  print "Starting...\n";

  $connection = Net::AMQP::RabbitMQ->new();
  $connection->connect('localhost', { user => 'guest', password => 'guest', port => 5672 });
  $connection->channel_open(++$channelId);
  print "Connected!\n";

  # send first message
  sendToRabbit({ message => 'body 1' });

  # fork child
  my $child = fork();
  if(!$child) {
    # child
    sleep(1);
    print "child exiting...\n";
    exit(0);
  }
  else {
    # parent
    waitpid($child, 0);
  }
  print "parent continuing...\n";

  # send second message - this will not be actually sent.  
  sendToRabbit({ message => 'body 2' });

  # allow I/O to settle...
  sleep(1);
}

main();
```

## EDIT: A solution

Thanks to *ikegami* for shedding light on the solution!

In my RabbitMQ management object, I've injected some code into the `connect()` routine that allows me to selectively skip the destructor for forked children that do not call `connect()` themselves.  This seems to have the desired effect.

```
# Connect to RabbitMQ and create a channel
sub connect {
  my ($self) = @_;

  $self->{pid} = $$;

  # if we redefined the destructor and connect is called, we need to revert
  # it so it can be redefined again properly
  no warnings qw( redefine );
  if($self->{original_destructor}) {
    # reset original destructor
    *Net::AMQP::RabbitMQ::DESTROY = $self->{original_destructor};
    delete $self->{original_destructor};
  }

  # define alternate destructor so forked children that do not call "connect" do
  # not destroy our connection
  {
     $self->debug("Overridding constructor...");
     $self->{original_destructor} = Net::AMQP::RabbitMQ->can('DESTROY');
     # only destroy the connection if the current pid is the owner's pid
     my $new_destructor = sub { if($self->{pid} eq $$) { $self->debug("Destroying $_[0]!\n"); $self->{original_destructor}->(); } };
     *Net::AMQP::RabbitMQ::DESTROY = $new_destructor;
  }

  my $connection = Net::AMQP::RabbitMQ->new();
  $connection->connect('localhost', { user => $self->{username}, password => $self->{password}, port => $PORT, vhost => $VHOST });
  $self->{connection} = $connection;
  $self->{channel} = $self->createChannel();

  1;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The child is a clone of the parent, and the file handles the parent has are shared with the child. As a copy of the parent, the child has a copy of `$connection`. When the child exits, this object is destroyed, calling it's destructor, sending a command to RabbitMQ to close the connection.

You can see this by adding

```
{
   my $old_destructor = Net::AMQP::RabbitMQ->can('DESTROY');
   my $new_destructor = sub { print("Destroying $_[0]!\n"); $old_destructor->(); };
   no warnings qw( redefine );
   *Net::AMQP::RabbitMQ::DESTROY = $new_destructor;
}
```

Possible solutions:

- Move the child code to a separate file, and `exec` that file.
- Move the child code into a sub that's called when the script is called with a "secret" parameter, and have the child restart itself via `exec` with that parameter.
- Create the child sooner. Specifically, create it before creating the RabbitMQ connection.
- Create a child to do the RabbitMQ stuff.
- Use a thread instead of a child process.

---

PS — Don't write `fork`+`exec` code yourself. At least use `open3`.

```
sub spawn {
  open(local *CHILD_STDIN, '<', '/dev/null') or die $!;
  return open3('<&CHILD_STDIN', '>&STDOUT', '>&STDERR', @_);
}

sendToRabbit({ message => 'body 1' });

my $pid = spawn('child.pl');    
waitpid($pid, 0);

sendToRabbit({ message => 'body 2' });
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick and detailed answer... I figured it was something like this but did not know how to verify it (thanks for the snippet).  +1.